# asp.net razor : retrieve data from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I m new in MVC framework. my query  is  i  have to  receive data from database sql
 database. and display  in .cshtml
 .plz help....

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = (from p in am.AMS_Page_Accesses
                     where p.Role_id == "m"
                     select new {
                      p.Name,
                      p.Id,
                      p.Link
                      }).ToList();
        var  abc= new linkname
          {    

          }  

       return View(abc);
    }
```

Model

```
public class linktab
    {            
        public  string id { get; set; }
        public  string Name { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }    
    }
    public class linkname
    {
        public List<linktab> menu { get; set; }
    }
```

in .cshtml

```
 @foreach (var a in Model)
    {
     <div>a.Name</div>
     <div>a.Id</div>
     <div>a.Link</div>
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong? Your code seems fine.

Comment: post your entire controller action code please - the current code looks ok as david says can't see anything wrong with just those two snippets.

Comment: error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
@foreach (var a in Model)--- error here--
{

Comment: The model you are passing to the view is empty.  You need to populate it with something for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show what exactly is your view's model, according to the error you got it seems you did not specify it at all (using the `@model` directive).

Try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = (from p in am.AMS_Page_Accesses
                 where p.Role_id == "m"
                 select new linktab
                 {
                     Id = p.Id,
                     Link = p.Link,
                     Name = p.Name
                 }).ToList();

    var abc = new linkname
    {
        menu = model
    }  

    return View(abc);
}
```

In your view:

```
@model linkname


@foreach (var a in Model.menu)
{
   <div>a.Name</div>
   <div>a.Id</div>
   <div>a.Link</div>
}
```

Comment: You did not update your action method according to my code...Because I don't have an anonymous type anywhere there. Note that there is `select new linktab` and not just `select new` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending an Empty collection change you action like this,

**I'm assuming that your view it's strongly typed to the List of linktab**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = (from p in am.AMS_Page_Accesses
                 where p.Role_id == "m"
                 select new linktab{
                  Name = p.Name,
                  id = p.Id,
                  link = p.Link
                  }).ToList();

   return View(model);
}
```

**If it's not the case and your model it's strongly type to the class linkname you should do your action like this**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = (from p in am.AMS_Page_Accesses
                 where p.Role_id == "m"
                 select new linktab{
                  Name = p.Name,
                  id = p.Id,
                  link = p.Link
                  }).ToList();
    linkname abc= new linkname
    {    
       menu = model
    }  
   return View(abc);
}
```

And you may change the code in your view something like this

```
@foreach (var a in Model.menu)
{
    <div>a.Name</div>
    <div>a.Id</div>
    <div>a.Link</div>
}
```